# How to compare the columns of the query statement in SQL

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have an `SQLite` database that stores image information.There is a column called "wide" and the other one is called "high". Now I need to check out all the vertical picture, how do I set the SQL statement?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're asking for is how to return the information for all the images where the height is greater than the width. In which case, I think you want something like this:

```
select *
  from <table name>
 where high > wide
;
```

Answer (score -1):

in ormlite can use ".le("picture_width", new ColumnArg("picture_height"))
"